# jquery draggable and droppable - stop inheriting parents css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable, droppable

This is hard to explain but I have draggable and droppable elements on my page. Some of the droppable elements have draggable elements inside them already but most don't.

When you hover over the droppables a back-ground image appears so you know your hovering over it. However, when you move a draggable into another droppable, now hovering over the newly moved draggable a background image appears in the OLD droppable which used to contain it.

if you look here you can see my problem: - try moving one of the yellow boxes around and then hover over it after you've moved it. The background image appears in the initial position. 
http://liquidlizard.net/

Can anyone tell me how to sort this out? I'd appreciate it :)

**EDIT** here's some of the code I'm using

```
<div id="row-2col0" class="empty"><div class="position"><a href class="bookmark" target="_blank"></a></div></div>
<div id="row-2col1" class="empty"><div class="position"></div></div>
<div id="row-2col2" class="empty"><div class="position"></div></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({start: function() {var initialposition = ???}});
$('.droppable').droppable({drop: handleDropEvent, accept:'.bookmark'});
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {

}
```

CSS:

```
.empty:hover{background-image:url(../img/tilehover.png);}
```

Basically everything has a class 'empty' which shows the background image when the item is hovered over.

Comment: It's probably because jQuery-UI caches your old DOM Object. You can re-assign the background ( css() ) again on "update" or "stop" (draggable parameters).

Comment: Please post your code in the question for posterity.

Comment: @Allendar thanks for taking time to answer. Can you explain a little more what you mean though, I'm new to javascript. I know what you mean about the update and stop params (I'm using the drop event of droppable for something else) but I'm not sure how I reassign the background?

Comment: See this Draggable API Doc: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/ Read up on the stop parameter. This way you can execute code when the drag is is done (stopped). What you want to do inside there is calling $('#yourTargetClassOrID').css('background-image', 'url=\'images/bg.png\''); . Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Allendar thanks again. I read the jquery stuff and I think I understand what its all about but I'm not sure it solves my problem. I think what you are suggesting would add a background image to a specific div (id or class). I already have the background image showing ok, it's just that when you move a draggble out from inside a droppable and place it elsewhere it seems to remain in the initial div...   PS... I updated my question with some code so you can see how I have it

Comment: I don't see it change back. I'm sorry to misunderstand. Is it about when you drag a green box out of a bookmarked block?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your dragged element is a child of the div it came from, so when you assign the `empty` class to that element, because your dragged element is a child of that didv, your  CSS rule, `.empty:hover` comes into play.

---

To avoid this problem, put a second div inside of each box, like this:

1. Add a new div inside of the div with the class `empty`.

   So this line:  (and all the ones like it)

   ```
   <div id="row-2col3" class="empty"><div class="position"></div></div>
   ```

   Changes to this: (I broke it down to make it easier to read.)

   ```
   <div id="row-2col3" class="empty">
       <div class = "elementContainer">      <!-- This is added..-->
           <div class = "wordHolder"></div>  <!-- ...............-->
       </div>                                <!--................-->
       <div class="position"></div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Then add this to your CSS:

   ```
   .elementContainer {
       position:relative;
   }

   .wordHolder {
       position:absolute;
       width:65px;
       height:65px;
   }
   ```
3. And finally, replace your CSS rule `.empty:hover` with `elementContainer:hover` and it should work!

> ---

**How and Why it works**

To quote [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp),

> An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is `<html>`:

So using `.elementContainer` with the relative attribute set serves as our container for our absolutely positioned elements with the class `wordHolder`. And they do not get in the way because they are removed from the regular flow and all the other elements act as if it did not exist.

You can read more about positioning elements here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Hope this helps!